# How do you make this dogeared shape with css only

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

[image: dogear]Can anyone show me (and explain) how to create this image with CSS only and with 1 shape (50x50px)a square with a transparent "dogear" on the bottom right?

I've been playing with triangles and circles with borders, but this has extra sides which I can't figure out on my own how to build. Thanks.

Comment: Does the corner have to be transparent?

Comment: Yes sir the bottom corner is like a dog ear style that needs to be transparent. Thanks

Comment: This could help https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Found this, looks like what you need. http://jsfiddle.net/kdFdt/8/

Comment: Yeah I've spent a few hours with shapes from there. But this shape has extra sides.

Comment: Are you adding content/text inside the shape?

Comment: I will be adding <p> tags yes. That fiddle is a triangle under another div. (3 shapes) I need this in one shape?

Comment: something similar to ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dtnIv

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about using gradients?

```
div{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;    
  background:
   linear-gradient(135deg, #333 0%, #333 90%, transparent 90%, transparent 100%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dCc7G/

Comment: This was the best answer regarding CSS for this shape that quickly allowed me to use text inside of the element with the least amount of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This solution does not use CSS, but its just an alternate approach that you could consider too using SVGs.

```
<svg width="50" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
    <polygon id="mypol" points="0 0 50 0 50 25 25 50 0 50" fill="red"></polygon> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ufZd2/)

Comment: This is awesome! Not sure if its what I'll use but seriously thanks.

Comment: I came accross SVGs sometime back and fell in love with the ability to draw images and control them with CSS :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use pseudo element and box shadow :
http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BlLFm/

```
div {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin:auto;
}
div:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  border: #BDB479 solid 30px;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color:  transparent;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 500px #BDB479;
}
body {
  background:linear-gradient(to top, gray,yellow)
}
```

you can draw the triangle shape via borders or rotate the pseudo-element.

here some more examples to give ideas http://codepen.io/collection/LbCzx// or selected http://codepen.io/collection/KIkgz//

Comment: This is covering my text within p tags though? Do I have something wrong?

Comment: Can i have a look at your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

To do something similar with a dogeared upper left corner:

[image: dogeared div block]

Use the following:

CSS:

```
.status-caution {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffff99;
}

.status-good {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
}

.status-dogear {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #333 0%, #333 10%, transparent 10%, transparent 100%);
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <td class="status-caution status-dogear"> 5 </td>
  <td class="status-good"> 0 </td> <!-- for comparison without dogear -->
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With old school CSS and HTML:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LGa34/)**

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div class="corner"></div>

.corner {
    float:left;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 50px 50px 0 0;
    border-color: #cccc99 transparent transparent transparent;
}
#a {
    background: #cccc99;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
}
#b {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:200px;
    background: #cccc99;
}
#c {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    background: #cccc99;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
}
body {
    background: #eee;
}
```