# How can you add a dogear to a div or table cell using css?

Tags: css

How can you add a dogear to a div or table cell to produce something like...

[dogeared div block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQmUk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something similar in post [How do you make this dogeared shape with css only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568950/how-do-you-make-this-dogeared-shape-with-css-only).  It put the dog ear in the bottom right.  This does a more traditional dogear in the upper left.

Use the following:

CSS:

```
.status-caution {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffff99;
}

.status-good {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
}

.status-dogear {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #333 0%, #333 10%, transparent 10%, transparent 100%);
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <td class="status-caution status-dogear"> 5 </td>
  <td class="status-good"> 0 </td> <!-- for comparison without dogear -->
</table>
```